# Retrieve host info from a VM

Tags: virtual-machines, hypervisor

I know we are able to know if we are in a virtual machine. But i'm wondering if we can gether informations about host from a vm (ip, mac, os, ...).
Another question: if we do an http request from the vm, is the web site able to get information about host or the host hardware  ( mac address, ..) ?

Comment: >I know we are able to know if we are in a virtual machine.
Not really, that depend on guest settings...

Answer (score 3):

Usually, the answer is "no", unless the virtualization platform explicitly provides this kind of information to its guest systems (which is not a common occurrence).

You can detect which platform is in use (VMware, Hyper-V...) by examining the list of virtual devices in the guest system and their drivers, and also by checking if platform-specific guest components are present. But this will not tell you anything about the host system itself; which anyway could vary at any moment, if clustering is in use.

Comment: In a LInux VM you can run `virt-what` to find the underlying hypervisor.

Comment: Which will fail to show anything in case the hypervisor is configured to be undetectable. Which is certainly not how you would configure it in a business environment so offtopic here...

Comment: I did not know it was possible to make it undetectable. Thanks. And about the second question, a distant machine cannot get host MAC by analyzing a request from the vm (I don't know how NIC virtualization works) ?

Comment: A distant machine couldn't possibly know the MAC address *at all*, because that's visible only on the local network. Anyway, yes, virtual NICs have MAC addresses completely unrelated to those of the host systems.